# 19.10 - Wifi - Linksys AE2500-RM not recognized by system

Tags: wireless, 19.10, adapter, cisco

I see this has been asked before, but not for 19.10, and not for FIVE years.

Linksys AE2500-RM wi fi adapter not even popping up on my Wi Fi Settings when I plug it in.

In five years, has there been a better solution than XP drivers to make this work?

EDIT: lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2516:0004 Cooler Master Co., Ltd. Storm QuickFire Rapid Mechanical Keyboard 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

EDIT 2: removed the devide from it's USB port and plugged it into a different port, reran the command and got the following:

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13b1:003a Linksys AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2516:0004 Cooler Master Co., Ltd. Storm QuickFire Rapid Mechanical Keyboard

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Added lsusb output to original question

Comment: We see no USB wireless device at all. Are you quite certain that it was plugged in?

Comment: definitely.  Just tried it in another port and re-ran the command, now it includes this:

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13b1:003a Linksys AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236]

Answer (score 0):

There is no known native Linux driver for your 13b1:003a device.

Drivers are typically developed either directly by or in conjuntion with the device chipset manufacturer, in this case, Broadcom. They have provided no driver for this device nor any of the very few other Broadcom USB devices.

The alternative used to be to use Windows XP driver files and the ndiswrapper mechanism. However, ndiswrapper is poorly supported and hasn't worked properly on any recent Ubuntu version for many years.

The direct answer to your question, "In five years, has there been a better solution than XP drivers to make this work?" is that there is *no solution at all*, including ndiswrapper, to make this work.

I suggest that you purchase another fully supported USB wireless device.

Comment: Thank you.  Not great news but at least it's a well researched one.